# Is there an equivalent for AuFS (such as in Ubuntu) that has balanced branch writing for OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems, home-server

We're switching the OS on our media/file server from Ubuntu to Mac OS X (most likely OS X Server 3.0).

We've been using aufs and SnapRAID on Ubuntu and like its ability to have balanced branch writing (i.e., distribute files over all the drives), but I can't seem to find aufs for OS X.

Is there an equivalent FS to have balanced branch writing in OS X?  I've read that union doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can get mhddfs for MacOSX. I use it on a Mac Pro with eSATA enclosures to pool 8 drives together for my media server, and use SnapRaid to provide parity for protection. Works perfectly.

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided the source where you found it.  Is it the MacPorts version?

Comment: Yeah, you can get it from MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

I just open-sourced a half-implemented MacFUSE filesystem to do this.  Pooled reading worked, as far as I can remember.  Offered for reference / learning without implied warranty.  Don't blame me if it eats your files, sets fire to your curtains or kills your cat.  It'll probably do all three.

https://github.com/mungler/PoolFS

Comment: Thanks, gonna give mhddfs a go first. Will probably replicate my SnapRAID/mhddfs set-up as that was what I had on my Ubuntu server last.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that sits above an existing filesystem like AuFS does, however don't forget you can run ZFS on Mac which allows you to achieve lots of similar goals.. like copy-on-writing and snapshotting a single directory.

https://code.google.com/p/maczfs/

https://github.com/zfs-osx/

..but until that's mature .. what I'm doing is actually symlinking into mounted images - images which I effectively version control to get control of some components on my system the way I otherwise could with AuFS.